# How to remove git addons on my page after resolving merge issues?

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

Recently I had a merge conflict in git. After using some git commands I managed to resolve those conflicts, so my git gives a message that all is ok and up-to-date with branches and with production master. So I was happy that I resolved all conflicts. However - on my production page I noticed strange addons:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD 

MAIN PAGE CONTENT

=======
>>>>>>> branch
```

How can I remove them?

Comment: @phd indeed, thanks for noticing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git plants these in the text when a merge conflict occurs. Just use your text editor (or IDE) to remove them, add the file and commit it.

Comment: thanks for tip, where is this file?

Comment: @gileneusz This is the actual main page of your application - not something internal to git.